# cuda cooperative_groups::thread_group sync limit

Tags: cuda

Is there a limit to how many threads can be synced with the method cooperative_groups::thread_group.sync()?

Suppose I start a block with 1024 threads and want to sync them all can I do this with cooperative_groups::thread_group.sync(), or is this method warp bound as in it will sync a max of the number of threads in a warp (32 in my case)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For thread groups up to threadblock size, you can [sync those groups](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#groups-blocks-cg) using `.sync()`.  Note that your code must permit all threads in the group to reach the barrier.

If you use a grid-sized group, then you must launch your kernel as [a properly supported cooperative launch](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization-cg).  This is necessary to be able to use `.sync()` correctly with a grid-sized group.

Comment: Thank you. I can see I had a small bug in the code that confused me somewhat. I can see now that what you describe is the case, and indeed sync does sync all threads in the block.